# How to get exact extremely low P-value in R (on log scale or otherwise)

Tags: r, floating-point, regression, precision, numeric

I am running a linear regression model in R, and the association is very significant- the P-value is much lower than the standard 2.2e-16.

The t-statistic from the regression is -44.85
and the degrees of freedom are 33689.

Is there a way to get the exact P-value, or even the -log10(P)? I tried a few different things- first, the package Rmpfr does not have good support for the student's T distribution.

Also, there is this post: [Decimal points - Probability value of 0 in Language R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328784/decimal-points-probability-value-of-0-in-language-r), but the answer in the top-voted comment is not quite right.  Let's say we use the given example in that post:

```
d <- data.frame(x=rep(1:5,each=10))
set.seed(101)
d$y <- rnorm(50,mean=d$x,sd=0.0001)
lm1 <- lm(y~x,data=d)
```

From `coef(summary(lm1))` we can see that P = 9.690173e-203

The answer says we can get a log(P) (which is what I want) from:

`tval <- coef(summary(lm1))["x","t value"] 2*pt(abs(tval),df=48,lower.tail=FALSE,log.p=TRUE)/log(10)`

Which gives -404.6294.  This value is not the log(P). If we do -log10(9.690173e-203), the answer is  202.0137; which does not equal 404.6294 or 404.6294/2 = 202.3147.

Is there a workaround for this?  Greatly appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: `log` is in base `e` and not base 10

Comment: check `log(coef(summary(lm1))[2,4])` vs `pt(coef(summary(lm1))["x","t value"] , 48, lower.tail = FALSE, log.p = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks @onyambu, I checked them and they are close but not exactly equal.  How would you suggest getting the correct log (either base e or base 10) pval?  Sorry if I'm missing something extremely basic...

Comment: The only way they can be equal is to get 2*pt.. ie `log(pt(coef(summary(lm1))["x","t value"] , 48, lower.tail = FALSE)*2)` vs `log(coef(summary(lm1))[2,4])`

Comment: Thank you @onyambu, I guess then if we want the log (base e) p-value for my original example, where there is no way to get the exact p-value, then the best way would be to do `pt(coef(summary(lm1))["x","t value"] , 48, lower.tail = FALSE, log.p = TRUE)` and round the result to the nearest whole?

Comment: No that is one tailed. Note that the test is 2 tailed. Hence you must multiply by 2 before you do log. That is why I gave it as `log(2*pt(coef(summary(lm1))["x","t value"] , 48, lower.tail = FALSE))` It should be EXACTLY SIMILAR to `log(coef(summary(lm1))[2,4])`

Comment: simply `pt(coef(summary(lm1))["x","t value"] , 48, lower.tail = FALSE, log.p = TRUE) + log(2)`  You need to add `log(2)` to get the exact match if you need to use `log.p = TRUE`

Comment: Thank you @onyambu!  Indeed, when I do `pt(coef(summary(lm1))["x","t value"] , 48, lower.tail = FALSE, log.p = TRUE) + log(2)`, I get exactly the same as `log(coef(summary(lm1))[2,4])`. 

We can then use the change of base formula to get it into log10 (commonly used to report p-values):  e.g. the log10(P) is: `(pt(coef(summary(lm1))["x","t value"] , 48, lower.tail = FALSE, log.p = TRUE) + log(2)) / log(10)`

Comment: precise p values this low are not meaningful.

Comment: There are several applications in human genetics where such low p-values are observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
log(2) + pt(coef(summary(lm1))["x","t value"] , 48, lower.tail = FALSE, log.p = TRUE) 
[1] -465.1537
```

This is exactly similar to the log of the p-value:

```
log(coef(summary(lm1))[2,4])
[1] -465.1537
```

Comment: Thank you @onyambu, greatly appreciate your help.  Do you know of a way to get the z score from a log P-value?  For example, if the P is 5e-08, then z score is `qnorm(5e-08/2, lower.tail = FALSE, log.p = FALSE)`- but this returns Inf if the p is too small...

Comment: Never mind, this has been answered very nicely by @Ben Bolker !

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67560210/convert-p-to-z-in-log-space